# Information about php variable assignment

Tags: php, arrays, variable-assignment, var

Can you help me?
Is there someone can explain the meaning of this line of php code?

```
$options = ($options ?: array()) + $this->options;
```

Thanks

Comment: The keywords are: ternary operator, array merging.

Answer (score 0):

That is equivalent to this:

```
if (!$options)
  $options = array();

$options = $options + $this->options;
```

the `?:` is the ternary operator. If `$options` evaluates to true it is returned, otherwise an empty array is returned.

The `+operator` given two arrays creates a new array by concatenating them

Answer (score 0):

In short:

> *Create an array `$options` by merging the `$this->options` array into `$options`.*

```
$options ?: array()
```

If `$options` is *truthy* (presumably if it exists and is not `false`) this will return the `$options` value as is, otherwise it will return an empty array. [It's shorthand syntax for](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$options ? $options : array()
```

So the result of this is an array. To this, the `$this->options` array is added via `+`. The [`+` array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) adds any keys from the right to the left which don't already exists there.

So the result is a type-safe (in case `$options` is not an array) merger between the two option arrays. Note that "type safe" is relative, if `$options` is a number or an object or something else this'll still produce an error; but we'll assume `$options` could be either `false` or `null` or an `array` at this point, so it's probably fine as intended.